# Flex slide clearing

Tags: apache-flex, air

Hi I am new to flex programming. I am creating an mms creation environment and am adding slides to the videoDisplay component.I have a slot component that has videos to be played. The videos are added to the slide instance. Its working but I have a problem when replacing the video on the slide. The video instance is being removed but on adding another video the thumbnail of previous video is displayed on the slide but then plays the newly added video.
Please help me resolve this issue, here's the remove code below.

```
protected function removeSlide(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   if( slideTarget != null )
   {
      slide[slideTarget].reset();
      slide[slideTarget].slideToggle();
      //slide[slideTarget] = new Slide();
      textIndex = -1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with the `Video` object. When you re-use it, it always shows the last frame briefly (despite all of your efforts to call `video.clear()`).

The common solution is not to re-use the `Video` object. So somewhere in your code (perhaps when you call `slide[slideTarget].reset()`) you should throw out the previous `Video` object and instantiate a new one.

If you do a google search for this problem, you will see that this is a long standing problem.

Comment: Hi indeed this is a long standing problem. I have tried to instantiate the new object but the problem is still persisting. If I deal with images only on the videoDisplay I get the proper response. Only when dealing with video objects is when I get the problem.

Comment: If you still need help you should edit your question and show the code that you tried (when trying to instantiate a new Video object). Your code above is not enough to explain what is happening.